# Error while trying to do a prediction with bnlearn package - Bayesian network

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to do a prediction model with ***bnlearn package*** but I get error indicating : "Error in check.data(data) : the data are missing". 
Here is my example data set and line of codes that I used to preformed the prediction model:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " category birds    wolfs     snakes
                    yes        3        9         7
                    no         3        8         4
                   no         1        2         8
                   yes        1        2         3
                   yes        1        8         3
                   no         6        1         2
                   yes        6        7         1
                   no         6        1         5
                   yes        5        9         7
                   no         3        8         7
                   no         4        2         7
                   notsure    1        2         3
                   notsure    7        6         3
                   no         6        1         1
                   notsure    6        3         9
                   no         6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

Here are the lines of code that I used to get the prediction:

```
dat$birds<-as.numeric(dat$birds)
dat$wolfs<-as.numeric(dat$wolfs)
dat$snakes<-as.numeric(dat$snakes)
training.set = dat[1:8,2:4 ]
demo.set = dat[8:16,2:4 ]
res <- hc(training.set)
fitted = bn.fit(res, training.set)

pred = predict(fitted, demo.set) # I get an error: "Error in check.data(data) : the data are missing."
```

Any Idea how to solve it ?

Comment: You need to to specify the node to do predictions on. ie `predict(fitted, node="snakes", data=demo.set)`. To predict across all nodes you could use `sapply(names(fitted), function(i) predict(fitted, node=i, demo.set))`. Have a look at `?bnlearn:::predict.bn.fit` for how to specify arguments. [I think you already worked this out (given your subsequent, now deleted, question) - if so please could you write up an answer and accept it (so that it appears solved on SO).

Comment: Thanks user20650 for your help.I got what I was looking for with this line of code:predict(fitted, node="snakes", data=demo.set,method = "bayes-lw"). The method is critical here, without It I got the same predicted value for all observations.Please write your comment as an answer and I'll upvote for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*predict(fittedbn, node="column name to predict", data=testdata)* worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `bnlearn` installed, but from your code I guess that the problem is that you didn't provide the output (which is the category column) into the training set. Change:

```
   training.set = dat[1:8,]
```

and see if it works.